# Module not a task or void function

Tags: syntax-error, verilog, fork-join

I am trying to create a module for carry select adder in Verilog. Everything works fine except the following portion where it is causing compilation error.

```
module csa(a,b,s,cout);
input[15:0] a,b;
output [15:0] s;
output cout;
wire zero_c1, zero_c2,zero_c3,zero_c4,zero_c5;
wire one_c1, one_c2,one_c3,one_c4,one_c5;
wire temp_c1,temp_c2,temp_c3,temp_c4,temp_c5;
wire [15:0] s_zero, s_one;

initial
begin
fork
    fa(s[0], temp_c1,a[0],b[0],0);
    fa_one(s_zero[1],s_one[1],zero_c1,one_c1,a[1],b[1]);
    fa_two(s_zero[3:2],s_one[3:2],zero_c2,one_c2,a[3:2],b[3:2]);
    fa_three(s_zero[6:4],s_one[6:4],zero_c3,one_c3,a[6:4],b[6:4]);
    fa_four(s_zero[10:7],s_one[10:7],zero_c4,one_c4,a[10:7],b[10:7]);
    fa_five(s_zero[15:11],s_one[15:11],zero_c5,one_c5,a[15:11],b[15:11]);
join
end
```

When I try to compile that, it says:

> the module "fa", "fa_one" are not a task or void function

I deleted the `initial` statement, and now it says:

> Syntax error near "fork", expecting "endmodule"

I just want to run the code between `join` and `fork` in parallel. I have also confirmed that the modules `fa` and `fa_one` work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Verilog modules are not run or executed but instantiated, they represent physical blocks of hardware.

Everything is in parallel unless you have made effort to time share pieces of hardware. For example you might write an ALU core, which exists only once but use a program ROM to tell it which instruction to process every clockcycle.

Inside your modules you can have combinatorial code and sequential code.

**Combinatorial** logic will simulate in 0 time but will actually take some time for values to propagate through when placed on real devices.

If this propagation delay is not thought about and very large blocks of logic are created you will struggle to close timing on synthesis, due to the settling time through the logic being greater than the clock speed either side of the combinatorial logic.

**Sequential** logic implies that the results are held in flip-flops, which only update on clock edges. This means chains of sequential logic can take many clock cycles for data to propagate.

When pipelining a processor you break individual section up with flip-flops giving each section a full clock cycle for combinatorial propagation, at the expense of taking several clock cycles to calculate a single result.

To correct your example you would just have:

```
module csa(
  input  [15:0] a,
  input  [15:0] b,
  output [15:0] s,
  output        cout
);
wire zero_c1, zero_c2,zero_c3,zero_c4,zero_c5;
wire one_c1, one_c2,one_c3,one_c4,one_c5;
wire temp_c1,temp_c2,temp_c3,temp_c4,temp_c5;
wire [15:0] s_zero, s_one;

fa       ufa(s[0], temp_c1,a[0],b[0],0);
fa_one   ufa_one(s_zero[1],s_one[1],zero_c1,one_c1,a[1],b[1]);
fa_two   ufa_two(s_zero[3:2],s_one[3:2],zero_c2,one_c2,a[3:2],b[3:2]);
fa_three ufa_three(s_zero[6:4],s_one[6:4],zero_c3,one_c3,a[6:4],b[6:4]);
fa_four  ufa_four(s_zero[10:7],s_one[10:7],zero_c4,one_c4,a[10:7],b[10:7]);
fa_five  ufa_five(s_zero[15:11],s_one[15:11],zero_c5,one_c5,a[15:11],b[15:11]);
endmodule
```

NB: it is `module_name #(parameters) instance_name ( ports );`

Answer (score 1):

`fork` is used to run procedural statements within a module in parallel.  Separate module instances always run in parallel.

Child modules are instantiated directly within their parent module, not within an `initial`, `begin`, or `fork` which are used for procedural statements.  So you can remove the `initial`, `begin`, `fork`, `join`, and `end`, and add an `endmodule` at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I modified the code. It's compiling fine now.             Just one question. So all instances of "fa", "fa_one" will now run in parallel? What if there was some relation between them (e.g. fa_one use the output of fa)?

Comment: Yes all instances will run in parallel.  It depends how you've written the modules but if they just contain primitives and/or continuous assignments then the outputs will be recomputed whenever the inputs change.